# Show that we can find a matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such that $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{I}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, vectors

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. For every two-dimensional vector $\mathbf{v}$, there exists a two-dimensional vector $\mathbf{w}$ such that
$\mathbf{A} \mathbf{w} = \mathbf{v}.$ Show that we can find a matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such that $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{I}$.

I'm not sure how to prove this and I have no idea where to start. Help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, then you'll get such $B$. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: I agree with @JoséCarlosSantos that a good question will include any efforts you have made and any thoughts that you have - even if these have not got you anywhere. It is also helpful to have an indication of your mathematical level. Sadly we regularly have people who just want answers to their homework without effort, and you will receive a much more positive response from the community if you show you are not one of them, but are interested in actually learning mathematics. Then you will get a lot of useful help.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick The OP says that $\mathbf{Aw}=\mathbf v$ has a solution for all $\mathbf v$, which is equivalent to $\mathbf A$’s being invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked it. Thanks !! @amd

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take
$$ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then you can find vectors $w_1, w_2$ so that $Aw_j = v_j, \; j = 1,2.$

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mainly asking for a hint about how to start, rather than a full solution - you should help people to give you the kind of answer which will help you most by making that explicit in your question. in general you get very little from just seeing someone else's solution to a question like this - you need to train your brain into the right ways of thinking about such problems.

Here is a hint: can you see how choosing suitable vectors for $v$ could help?

For future use - when you are given a general property like this, and also have a specific goal in mind, how can you choose values in the general property which relate to your specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Since for every $2D$ vector $v$, we can find $w$ such that $$Aw= v$$then let $w_1$ and $w_2$ such that 
$$Aw_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$Aw_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Hence 
$$A \begin{bmatrix} w_1 & w_2 \end{bmatrix} = I$$
So your matrix $B = \begin{bmatrix} w_1 & w_2 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: and why was it downvoted ?

Comment: Mine was as well. We should have probably let OP present some of his/her own efforts.